# How can I manipulate Node.prototype so that a Node.style.styleProperty becomes Node.styleProperty

Tags: javascript

---

What I'm trying to do is make this declaration:

```
Element.style.display = "none"
```

The same as this declaration:

```
Element.display = "none"
```

I also want to make this:

```
Element.style.background = "#fff"
```

do the same thing as this:

```
Element.bg = "#fff"
```

How do I do this?

---

Comment: please provide some information about what lang you  are using or what you trying to do for example scrapping or trying to style some html elements etc...

Comment: No, you almost certainly [don't want to do that](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: Are you familiar with [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#defining_getters_and_setters)?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to loop through all the keys of `element.style` and use javascript `getter` and `setter` to provide this behaviour. In this case element is instance of Element. Below is a sample code:

```
Object.keys(element.style).forEach(key => {
    Object.defineProperty(element, key, { 
      get: function() {
        return element.style[key];
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        element.style[key] = newValue;
      }
    });
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Using the `getter` we access the `element.style[key]` for example `element.style.bg`, and using the `setter` we can apply the new value to the `element.style[key]` for example to `element.style.bg`.

Comment: I am just providing an outline on how it can be achieved, it will need an instance of Element before this code works. @Bergi

Comment: Well that is how I understood the question :D I thought that OP had some sort of document.getElementById or something and was generalising by using Element.

Comment: I was @ssBarBee